# Major product monochlorination of 2-methylpropane

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides

> What is the major product of monochlorination of 2-methylpropane and for 2-methylbutane?

**My attempt:** as in 3 degree position, monochlorination is favoured (due to free radical formation), so according to me, it should be 2-chloro-2-methylpropane and same as in other 2-chloro-2-methylbutane.

But, it is stated to be incorrect. The correct answer is 1-chloro-2-methylbutane. Why's that the correct answer instead?

Comment: 1-chloro-2-methylbutane makes no sense to form as the major product. I highly suspect you are right, and the key might be wrong.

Comment: For each example consider the relative reactivity of each type of CH bond and the number of each one. http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/StudyAids.html#Radical

Comment: @PrittBalagopal on the contrary, Cl isn't selective enough (contrary to bromine)

Comment: @Mithoron I believe that would simply reduce the % of 2-chloro-2-methylbutane in the product mixture as compared to other products, but I don’t really think it could actually flip the scenario (make 1-chloro more preferable).

Comment: And here I wonder why no one in 9 hours marked it as dupe of first question on the "related" list...